# Internet Explorer doesn't connect JSON via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, sharepoint-2010, internet-explorer-10

I'm working on a dynamic table on SharePoint 2010 Web Part fed with JSON data, called from a url. This was successful in Chrome. When I try to print the same on Internet Explorer 10 the data is always a table with a header and a single row with {{items.domain}}, {{items.project}}, and all the others, because it can't connect with the url on my Ajax connection.

It's IE fault or it's something wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="tableJson">

<head>
<script src="/sites/JqueryDemo/JS/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<link href="/sites/JqueryDemo/JS/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<script src="/sites/JqueryDemo/JS/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="tableJsonCtrl">
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
      <td>domain</td>
      <td>project</td>
      <td>username</td>
      <td>host</td>
      <td>Login_time</td>
      <td>Last action</td>
      <td>client_type</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="items in phones">
      <td>{{items.domain}}</td>
      <td>{{items.project}}</td>
      <td>{{items.username}}</td>
      <td>{{items.host}}</td>
      <td>{{items.Login_time}}</td>
      <td>{{items.Last_action}}</td>
      <td>{{items.client_type}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
 <script>

var jsonTable
var json = (function () {

    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': "http://myurl:8080/users",
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {        
            jsonTable = data;   
        }
    });

})();

    var tableJson =  angular.module('tableJson', []);
    tableJson.controller('tableJsonCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.phones = jsonTable;

    }) 

</script> 
<script src="/sites/JqueryDemo/JS/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with angular code.

Basic rule of thumb is jQuery code should be wrapped in [ready](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=ready) function. Please move all your JS code inside ready and try.